# Why does my website scroll slowly, and why are its hover effects laggy? How can I fix this?

Tags: html, css, performance, drupal, lag

So I have this site [here](http://www.whackk.com) which has major performance issues. Scrolling is *very* slow, hover effects have a bit of lag and other similar issue. Unfortunately right now I am working off a cheap host so I don't have the option to gzip my files and I am not sure how big a contributing factor that is, though. For what it's worth, I am using Drupal as a CMS.

I would like to know the various reasons for the lag and what I can do to fix it.

Some about:memory stats for the homepage :

Memory:
- Private:49664k
- Shared:13052k
- Total: 62716k

Virtual Memory:
- Private : 53400k
- Mapped : 10412;

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Don't use `background-size:cover`. It's slow. Disabling it completely eliminates the scrolling issues.

Comment: that does actually fix it! thanks. but then the background ends up looking shitty. any alternatives to `background-size:cover`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems fine on my machine (2009 MacBook Pro running Chrome 10), but I think you need to pick apart the idea of “performance”.

gzipping reduces the size of the text files that make up your site, so it reduces the time required for them to get from your web server to end users’ machines. That happens before the page loads in the user’s browser. It doesn’t affect the scrolling speed of the page once it’s loaded.

There does seem to be a metric crap-ton of JavaScript files included on the page, a few of which have “scroll” in their name. I’m not sure if any of them are running when the user scrolls, and thus slowing the browser down, but it seems like the most likely candidate for slow scrolling. (Ooh — unless meagar’s comment about `background-size: cover;` is right.)

**Edit:** as `background-size: cover` seems to be the issue, I’d suggest removing it, and making your background image reasonably big, so that it looks acceptable at most screen resolutions. You might want to get whoever made the image to edit it so that it fades out to a single color at the edges, so that it blends into your `background-color` for users on higher resolutions.

Comment: the gzipping part was just an idea. When I say performance, I mean after the page has loaded. And the symptoms have been mentioned already - lag in scrolling, hover effects..

Comment: @vr3690: sure, I know — just explaining why gzipping probably has nothing to do with your problem. My answer did come across as a bit negative, apologies.

Comment: no worries. the "scroll" js files are all jquery plugins. possible suspects, will have to check them out.

Comment: @vr3690: yeah, you do seem to be using *a lot* of jQuery plugins. Although JavaScript performance in browsers has come on in leaps and bounds in recent versions, you want to be careful.

Comment: I know. Next on my to-do list is cutting down on the total amount of JS being used. meager was right though, removing `background-size:cover` instantly fixed the scrolling issues.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the background image and positioning using Firebug and the scrolling instantly speeded up.

Part of the speed will be the various JavaScript components, but the most noticable 'lag' was the fixed 2000x2000 image specified in the CSS for the HTML element.

Comment: yes, meager pointed out the same. there wasn't actually any need to completely remove the background. apparently `background-size:cover` was the main culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Well, CMS usually cause a lot of lag. Why: because they have a tendency to boast a convoluted pile of malarkey called JavaScript, which seduces the user to utilize by offering simple usage. In most cases, JavaScript is essentially useless. I have encountered websites that looked good, but that give even my newest alienware-gaming-machine indigestion. Reason is: JavaScript was used, for nearly everything. This slows things down, immensely, whether you use a CMS or copy-paste a custom webpage.

Simple design rule I've learnt: use JavaSript when necessary for a task. Never, ever in cases where it does not add any functionality, or do it only when you are learning and want to test thing and naturally when your customers keep banging at your door because they want animated pop-ups, parallax scrolling and the like.

There are instances, where you will need JS, even for eyecandy, but on too many pages, it is too much. Result: people will love your webpage, where your photo gallery page won't take 15 seconds to display a meezly new picture or the scrolling speed will make you think that the internet was actually "faster" in the early 1990s...